# Getting a different output in loop

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public static void main ( String[] argv ) {
        Scanner  in   = new Scanner(System.in);
        int      n    = in.nextInt();
        String[] name = new String[n];
        String[] num  = new String[n];
        String   s;
        String   v;
        int      flag = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            name[i] = in.next();
            num[i] = in.next();
        }

        while (in.hasNext()) {
             s = in.next();               // query
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 flag = 1;
                 if (s.equals(name[i])) {
                     System.out.println(name[i] + "=" + num[i]);
                     flag = 1;
                 } else {
                     flag = 0;
                 }
             }
             if (flag == 0) System.out.println("Not found");    
         }
     }
}
```

This is the code and i am getting 
And the code has name and numbers and a query strings!

```
sam=99912222
Not found
Not found
harry=12299933
```

Why there is "Not found" two times?
It should be printed only once as there is only one query that is not in the array! Unable to understand

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger?

Comment: you are mad, please calm down

Comment: The formatting of your code was DREADFUL.  I made it presentable.  You will find it much easier to find errors if you aren't fighting code that looks like it was typed by drunken monkeys.

Comment: Have you learned about the `bool` type yet?  Because `flag` would be better as a `bool` than an `int.`  Also, consider naming if something like `found`.

Comment: Ask yourself this question.  In one trip around the `while`-loop, is it possible that both `System.out.println`s happen?

Comment: Yup!
I program drunk! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave the for loop after setting `flag` to 1.
Right now you check whether `s` equals all elements in `name`.
Add

```
break;
```

after

```
System.out.println(name[i]+"="+num[i]);
flag=1;
```